# realtime monitoring of linux server network

Tags: network-monitoring, elasticsearch, prometheus

We have a few Linux server which act as Edge network, We want realtime (or near-realtime) information on network bandwidth, top IP addresses and network bandwidth per them and other network parameters so we can see the overall status of our network and find special cases like when we are under attack.

We also need to store and visualize this information with tools like Grafana etc.

I know we can get metrics like total bandwidth using `Prometheus node exporter` but this solution cannot handle things like top IP addresses, IP addresses can be gathered using `elasticsearch` but using our elasticseach has up to 30 minutes delay which is too much for us (in cases like attacks)

Is there any other solution to gather this kind of information fast?

Answer (score 0):

https://opmantek.com/network-management-system-nmis/
NMIS is open source, but commercially backed with paid for modules.